# db2 insert trigger new is not valid

Tags: database, plsql, triggers, db2, database-trigger

I've defined this trigger:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TRIGGER actualizarSaldoIngreso
BEFORE INSERT ON Ingreso
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN
    UPDATE Cuenta SET Saldo = Saldo + NEW.Cantidad WHERE IBAN = NEW.Cuenta_IBAN;
END@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

But db2 returns this error. Any ideas to solve it?

```
"NEW.CANTIDAD" is not valid in the context where it is used.
```

Comment: Your syntax is not valid, you must use the REFERENCING clause in the trigger definition to link an alias for the NEW row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TRIGGER actualizarSaldoIngreso
BEFORE INSERT ON Ingreso
REFERENCING NEW as N
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN
    UPDATE Cuenta SET Saldo = Saldo + N.Cantidad WHERE IBAN = N.Cuenta_IBAN;
END@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```